# select sum(columnName) from TableName groupby columnName , how i can get same result without using group by

Tags: sql, group-by

Table Name:emp

```
Salary      Designation 
3000            A
4000            B
5000            C
2000            A
1000            B

sql>select sum(salary) from emp group by designation;

Result 
A  5000
B  5000
C  5000
```

**Question: how i can get same result without using group by.**

Comment: `if(sc.hasNextLine())`

Comment: Please... I beg of you... format your code!!!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tried both hasNext and hasNextLine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a debugger to see the value of data at the time of the `println` statement?

Also, Why not change the `if(sc.hasNext())` to `while(sc.hasNext())` to print everything from the scanner?

If the scanner contains X number of lines, then you need to call nextLine() X number of times to read all of the lines. The if statement only calls nextLine() once, and the while statement calls nextLine() until sc.hasNext() is false, which is X times.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this without `GROUP BY`? I see no sense in this. Anyway, you can do this by selecting the distinct designations first and then get their salary sums in a subquery:

```
select (select sum(salary) from designations d2 where d2.designation = d.designation)
from (select distinct designation from designations) d;
```